# Tab Control tab will only use Wait Cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, tabcontrol

So, I'm making a game in C#, and I've created a window to handle custom controls schemes.

On this page there is a tab Control, with three tabs: Scheme 1, Scheme 2, and Custom

Scheme 1 and 2 are perfectly fine, but on the Custom tab, whenever the mouse hovers over it, it displays the wait cursor. The controls inside the tab work perfectly fine and without lag, but it just always displays the waitcursor.

I can't change the cursor property in the Design window (it just goes back to waitCursor), and I've tried changing it in code, but it won't work.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a child control on your third tab that is causing the wait cursor to show?  Also, when are you trying to set the cursor in code?  You would need to make sure you try to do it in the tab load event.

Comment: There's a button (to start the key assignment sequence), and that won't get it's cursor changed either.

I don't see a tab load event, but I tried it in the form load, and the tab Index Changed events

Comment: Have you tried changing the designer property and they rebuilding the project?

Comment: The designer property quite literally won't change. I click it and select a different cursor from the drop down menu, and it stays as WaitCursor

Comment: Were you able to try my solution below to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following property in your tab control and each tab:

UseWaitCursor set to true

If UseWaitCursor = true for a parent control then it will propagate this property to all child controls.  I think this is probably your issue.  Please see the link below for an explanation of the property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.usewaitcursor.aspx